# MySQL - CONCAT - Is there any way to concat a string and use it as a variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, concatenation

Low hours on mysql but starting to probe the edges. Stackoverflow a great resource - thanks everyone.

Experimenting with Concat I fell over this issue.  I know there will be a way but I just can't figure it out.

My example:

```
set @strokes_hole_10 = 6;
set @x = 10;
set @strokes = concat('strokes_hole_',@x);
select @strokes;
```

I looking for @strokes to be the variable value 6 rather than the variable value "strokes_hole_10".

I find lots of information on using concat, mostly straight forward examples and I know concat is resulting in a string.  I just can't figure out how to make a dynamic label work.

Am I looking at prepared statements as the way to proceed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have variable column name, you will need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
set @strokes_hole_10 = 6;
set @x = 10;
set @strokes = concat('@strokes_hole_',@x); -- add @ to variable string

-- generate the query string
set @query_str = CONCAT('SELECT ', @strokes);

-- prepare statement using the query string
Prepare stmt From @query_str;

-- executes the prepared statement
Execute stmt;

-- clean up after execution
Deallocate Prepare stmt;
```

**Result**

```
| @strokes_hole_10 |
| ---------------- |
| 6                |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGpsF8zK34az4ssbA32Cmn/0)

Comment: set @strokes = concat('@strokes_hole_',@x,' into @var');

Comment: @ereceles I don't understand what you are asking for ?. You are missing a select in the concat

Comment: Just added the variable into line three to be able to pass this result to a stored procedure.  Published so others could see the solution.  thks